# Memory/performance trading question?

Tags: iphone, button, png, alpha

What is the best?

I want to handle about 400 buttons (the buttons have 4 state).
What is the best? To store/display 4 different OPAQUE image for each button, or assamble the states from 2 ALPHA MASKED png?

I know that the question is a bit foggy.
More OPAQUE image, or less but ALPHA MASKED?

If there's any experience, please share.

Comment: Ehm, you're actually trying to show 400 buttons at the same time? That would make every button max. `sqrt((320 * 480) / 400) = 20x20`. Don't think that really makes sense, does it?

Comment: :) Paginated scrolling. Only 12 button will be visible at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned before, I really don't think this would be a good idea (from an UX perspective). However, if you do want to do this, you should 'hack' a little bit to increase the performance.

Instead of using 400 (or even `400 * 4 = 1600`) `UIView`s (or `UIButton`s, which would basically be the same in this case), you should stick to one subclassed `UIView` and override the `drawRect:` method for faster and cached drawing.

You can override the `touchesBegan ...`, `touchesMoved ...`, etc. events to track touch events. When a user presses one 'button' (actually, it presses in your single view, but you can measure in what button it'ld be), you update a single `int`-variable and call `setNeedsDisplay` to redraw the 'buttons'.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. Of course only 12 * 3 button will be loaded at once only. The rest will be loaded lazy on scroll events. I'm implementing the drawRect method with the custom state accessors, hope it will be fast enough. I'm planning to create the CGlayers at init, then just redraw them on state changes. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: I suggest only creating 12 buttons, and simply modifying their labels when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where exactly you'll be using them. If we are talking about static positions - use alpha masked. On tables(and any scroll enabled views) you need to check performance first.

Comment: Yeah, they will be scrolled. I'll use Tim's approach below. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Btw, I've found for my purposes, that using subviews making scroll a much smoother then drawing the cell (thought I have something about 7 subviews on the cell. 4 of them buttons. I must actually add on that, that my cell was pretty big one with different height - between 120 to 300 px.)